# putting objects on top of other objects

Tags: java, object, visibility

i have this jpanel, which at first i have under my other panels, but then after i use the panel, then it goes in front, and then i cannot display the text on the other panels, how do i force these other panels on top of the first panel .. ?? any suggestions are welcome..

to the comments: well, i don't use a layout manager, and its when i set it to visible=false and then makes another object on top, then when i set visible=true then i cannot read the labels on the now visible object.

Comment: Improve your question by adding code snippets and/or screenshots.. Otherwise you wont get any practical help as your question as it is is a bit unclear.

Comment: Your question is a bit vague, so the only answer that I can provide is; Use a layout manager correctly.

Comment: Reminds me of the [Society for Putting Things on Top of Other Things](http://orangecow.org/pythonet/sketches/ontopof.htm)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can experiment with  `setComponentZOrder(Component comp, int index)`